# How often should we really use futures and actors? Any alternatives?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, future, actor

I've set out to create a physics engine with scala using concurrency.
I know for a lot of number crunching can be parallelized (which is important for the optimizations of things).

However I know abstractions of parallelism using actors or futures come with a lot of overhead. How often should I really use futures and actors? I would imagine making every numeric statement (like `factorial(4)` or `gcd(5,10)`) a future might make things more inefficient as now you're paying for that overhead on multiple levels and quite often.

Maybe there are better ways of parallelizing execution on a lower level in scala? What are your opinions on the frequency of futures and actors being used?

Comment: Well I don't know actors very well besides the fact that they're basically glorified functions of type `Unit => Any` which makes them pretty bad in my book already :D

but an alternative to `Future` would be the various `IO` Monads offered by e.g cats-effect or scalaz ZIO. both have very powerful concurrency primitives to works with and I'd recommend checking them out.

Comment: @DominicEgger 1) Uhm, no. They are glorified functions of type `Any => Unit` *with a mailbox.* 2) "Monads" are not an universal excuse for [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). @OP: your question has no meaningful answer. We cannot tell you *"Just use `Future`s and and Actors 40% of the time, and you will be fine."* If you need it, then use it. If you don't need it, then don't use it.

Comment: ah yeah that way around. my bad I'm pre coffee and my brain hasn't fully cycled yet.  But please elaborate where `IO` Monads are cargoculting when comparing to `Future` they're pretty much strictly more powerful?

Comment: @DominicEgger I'm not comparing `IO` to `Future`s. I'm just wondering what it all has to do with physics engines. And what physics engines have to do with factorials. Is `factorial(3)` on some remote server, and do we have to retrieve the `4` from some database asynchronously, when computing `factorial(4)`? What does it all have to do with `Future`s?

Comment: ah I understand. I really didn't read too much into that part of the question. but I assumed they were looking for something more powerful in regards to concurrency and parallelism than `Future` hence my recommendation of `IO` . @OP can you maybe shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is worth distinguishing between true **parallelism** and broader **concurrency**.

**Parallelism** is a way to make you code run faster by performing multiple computations at the same time. This can range from SIMD instructions on a CPU though to distributed applications on multiple servers. The choice of parallelism will depend on the nature of the problem.

**Concurrency** is a way to implement [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) by separating code into different sections which *appear to* execute at the same time. The primary goal is to allow the application to juggle multiple tasks even if it is executing on a single thread.

**Actors** and **Futures** are primarily used to implement concurrency. An actor takes a specific role in the overall system and appears to operate independently and asynchronously, making it easier to reason about the behaviour of that part of the system. Futures are a way to get away from strict linear execution by saying that an operation will happen at some indeterminate time in the future.

Scala does not really support SIMD instructions (perhaps because of the JVM foundations) but there are libraries for GPU acceleration which you should definitely look at if you are doing heavyweight calculations.

Simple task-level parallelism can be done with the **parallel collection** classes in Scala which will potentially use multiple threads in an efficient way.

Futures can be used to spawn tasks for parallel execution, but they lack control over scheduling (they start immediately) so it is better to use one of the Scala task libraries.

You can use actors for thread-level parallelism where the same computation is going to be performed multiple times during the execution of the application. The computation is wrapped in an actor and then that actor is replicated on multiple threads, cores or processors. Each computation is triggered by a message to the actor and the results are returned in to the main application using a second message. This is useful for long-running computations with small amounts of input and output data, but if there is too much data then the cost of moving it between processes may become a significant overhead.

And, of course, there are many ways of distributing code across multiple servers, and actors are a strong candidate for this approach. Moving the data around becomes the key concern at this point.

Comment: *"The computation is wrapped in an actor and then that actor is **replicated** on multiple threads, cores or processors."* - citation needed? Why "replicated"? When there is something in the mailbox, actor's `receive` will be executed by some thread, and it can be a different thread each time, but it doesn't mean that an actor is *"replicated on multiple threads"*. Restarting crashed actors also does not count as "replicating". Nothing is replicated, unless you explicitly create a whole bunch of actors.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful response. You said "libraries for GPU acceleration". Any specific reliable libraries you would recommend?

Also for more context I'm trying to set this up with scalajs using webworkers. I know that they have set up an execution context that utilizes this. I guess I'll have to investigate if they have an implementation of the parallel collections library that uses this.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have experience of using GPU acceleration in Scala, but there appear to be wrappers for OpenCL and some acceleration for Spark workloads.